# How to install DateTimePicker in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components

I have creating form fields. Here, i want to add `DateTimePicker`.

I have referred in google about some date time picker. i got so many.

```
DateTimePicker jQuery plugin
Bootstrap DateTimePicker.
```

My question is which plugin is best among them. and

How can i install that plugin?

1. Download directory and place where?
2. Install via cmd.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install or update your composer.
If you are using Ubuntu or Linux Operating System, open command prompt and run this command:
**composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-jui**
This will create the jui folder which contains all the required plugins such as datepicker or any other you want to use in your website.
Now you just have to place this code in your form.php in views folder

```
use yii\jui\DatePicker;
<?= $form->field($model, 'from_date')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::classname(), [
    //'language' => 'ru',
    'dateFormat' => 'MM-dd-yyyy',
    ]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jquery plugin for that. Yii2 has several widgets which you can use: Some of them are:

1) [Yii2 Jui DatePicker](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html)
2) [Kartik yii2-widget-datepicker](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker)
3) [2amigos yii2-date-picker-widget](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget)

You can use anyone of these.

Comment: How to install these widget into my project

Comment: 1st is Yii2 default widget so you can use it directly. For other two you need to install it using composer. Details are given on their respective pages.

Comment: I have using first one. It shows Class 'yii\jui\DatePicker' not found

Comment: Than may be Jui is not installed. You can install it using composer. Here is the link: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui

Comment: Yeah i have installed jui. No error. but calendar is not opening

Comment: <?= $form->field($model, 'dob')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::classname(), [
                        'dateFormat' => 'MM-dd-yyyy',
                    ]) ?>

Comment: Well, If Jui is installed then it should work. Are you getting any jquery error in your console?